# Deciphering a PHP Class

Tags: php, class, singleton

I'm trying to figure out what exactly is going on in the code below. Can someone point me in the right direction? This is from the first lines wordpress plugin which adds extra settings to menu items in the admin.

```
class Some_Class {
    private static $instance = null;
    public static function get_instance() {
        return null == self::$instance ? self::$instance = new self : self::$instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

The static function `get_instance` will return an instance of the class `Some_Class`. If the variable `$instance` is not set, it will create a new instance of the class and save it to this variable. if it is set, it will return the variable.

If used correct, this design pattern makes sure only one object can be created of this class at runtime.

Comment: It will, in short; Return a object of itself if self is not an instance, if self is set then it will return the old self.

Comment: Between your answer and the comment from @isnisn it now makes sense. Thanks!